# Node.js read and execute a Ruby file?

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, rubygems, npm

Is there a npm that can install and or use a ruby file as is and execute inside of node.js? I'm curious because I want want to run two different ruby scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really simple by using child_process#exec

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('./script.rb', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  console.log('error: ' + error);
});
```

Docs here: [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to call 'ruby ./script.rb', I guess it depends on how the script is set up...